# How to add a search field to a drop down menu that filters the content?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a drop down menu that allows a user to select the product code, but my company has a lot of available products so I'd like to add a search field that queries the list while they type. any suggestions about how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with any standard auto-suggest script. I will provide a sample as a jQuery/AutoComplete example, but this is *by no means* the only way to do so.

## Client-Side Code

```
($(function() {
    $(document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.productCode}')).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        MyController.suggest(request.term, 
            function(data, event) {
                response(data);
            });
     }});
```

## Server-Side Code

```
@RemoteAction public static String[] suggest(String term) {
    String[] results = new String[0];
    for(Product2 record:[SELECT ProductCode FROM Product2 WHERE ProductCode LIKE :'%'+term+'%' LIMIT 20 ORDER BY ProductCode ASC]) {
        results.add(record.ProductCode);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This is the most basic version you need to get started, but you can customize the results to different limits, showing the term in bold, etc, etc.